# Overflow issue with pop-up element/JQuery Chosen

Tags: css, jquery-chosen

I'm using the JQuery Chosen plugin on my form. When the choices drop down, it creates a vertical scrollbar.

I believe I understand why this is: I am floating the container and using overflow on its container to clear that float and that appears to be the culprit. However, floats and clears are paramount to my actual layout and so I can't just take them out to accommodate the Chosen plugin.

Here's a quick JS Fiddle to illustrate the issue. I am pretty stumped on how to solve this issue so thanks in advance for any suggestions.

http://jsfiddle.net/NmVXV/

CSS:

```
.container {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.main {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.select-chosen {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <br />
        <div>
            <select class="select-chosen" multiple>
                <option>Option A</option>
                <option>Option B</option>
                <option>Option C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I originally posted the wrong JS Fiddle... sorry. I had to Fork it to a new one. Please check the new link http://jsfiddle.net/NmVXV/. Original post updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the height of the div element to be large enough. For that to happen, you will have to set height of all parents of that div element.

Comment: That is not the solution I am looking for. The drop down choices should simply be outside of the layout without causing overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by changing my approach to clearing my floats from using overflow to using clearfix on the container:

http://jsfiddle.net/NmVXV/3/

```
.container {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 400px;
}
.main {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.select-chosen {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content:" ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```